# How to set an escaped json for AWS DMS with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-dms

The Terraform's example is [Resource: aws_dms_replication_task](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dms_replication_task)
I created a test resource as

```
resource "aws_dms_replication_task" "test" {
  migration_type            = "full-load"
  replication_instance_arn  = aws_dms_replication_instance.test-dms-replication-instance-tf.replication_instance_arn
  replication_task_id       = "test-dms-replication-task-tf"
  source_endpoint_arn       = aws_dms_endpoint.test-dms-source-endpoint-tf.endpoint_arn
  table_mappings           = jsonencode(file("${path.module}/test.json"))

  tags = {
    Name = "test"
  }

  target_endpoint_arn = aws_dms_endpoint.test-dms-target-endpoint-tf.endpoint_arn
}
```

The test.json file is

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "1",
      "rule-name": "Rule name 1",
      "rule-action": "rename",
      "rule-target": "schema",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "SCHEMA_1",
        "table-name": "TABLE_1"
      },
      "value": "main"
    }
  ]
}
```

When run the terraform apply, got this error

```
Error: InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid Table Mappings document. Invalid json Invalid json object
```

If use the format as example maybe ok

```
table_mappings            = "{\"rules\":[{\"rule-type\":\"selection\",\"rule-id\":\"1\",\"rule-name\":\"1\",\"object-locator\":{\"schema-name\":\"%\",\"table-name\":\"%\"},\"rule-action\":\"include\"}]}"
```

How to realize the same result if use Terraform's function?

Comment: Have you tried with just `table_mappings           = file("${path.module}/test.json")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your escaped json string, you can do:

```
table_mappings = jsonencode(jsondecode(file("${path.module}/test.json")))
```

This effectively removes `\n` from your `test.json` and produces single-line json escaped string.

Example:

```
"{\"rules\":[{\"object-locator\":{\"schema-name\":\"SCHEMA_1\",\"table-name\":\"TABLE_1\"},\"rule-action\":\"rename\",\"rule-id\":\"1\",\"rule-name\":\"Rule name 1\",\"rule-target\":\"schema\",\"rule-type\":\"transformation\",\"value\":\"main\"}]}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The `file("${path.module}/test.json")` works directly. It generated `table_mappings           = jsonencode(JSON_DATA)`. But your answer decode and encode may even better to make the data.

Comment: Is it possible to join multiple json files set to `table_mappings`? For example, there are more than one test.json files.

Comment: @Miantian I would suggest making new question with some examples of the files and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. I created a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534008/how-to-join-multiple-json-files-for-table-mapping-on-aws-dms-with-terraform