# How do I join multiple JSON files for table mapping on AWS DMS using Terraform?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-dms

In order to create a replication task of DMS, I use this resource:

```
resource "aws_dms_replication_task" "test" {
  migration_type            = "full-load"
  replication_instance_arn  = aws_dms_replication_instance.test-dms-replication-instance-tf.replication_instance_arn
  replication_task_id       = "test-dms-replication-task-tf"
  source_endpoint_arn       = aws_dms_endpoint.test-dms-source-endpoint-tf.endpoint_arn
  table_mappings           = file("${path.module}/db1/test1.json")

  tags = {
    Name = "test"
  }

  target_endpoint_arn = aws_dms_endpoint.test-dms-target-endpoint-tf.endpoint_arn
}
```

There are many JSON files generated by the schema, such as:

`./db1/test1.json`

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "1",
      "rule-name": "Rule name 1",
      "rule-action": "rename",
      "rule-target": "schema",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "SCHEMA_1",
        "table-name": "TABLE_1"
      },
      "value": "main"
    }
  ]
}
```

`./db1/test2.json`

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "2",
      "rule-name": "Rule name 2",
      "rule-action": "rename",
      "rule-target": "schema",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "SCHEMA_2",
        "table-name": "TABLE_2"
      },
      "value": "main"
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, I want to get a full `rules` JSON output like

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "1",
      "rule-name": "Rule name 1",
      "rule-action": "rename",
      "rule-target": "schema",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "SCHEMA_1",
        "table-name": "TABLE_1"
      },
      "value": "main"
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "2",
      "rule-name": "Rule name 2",
      "rule-action": "rename",
      "rule-target": "schema",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "SCHEMA_2",
        "table-name": "TABLE_2"
      },
      "value": "main"
    }
  ]
}
```

It seems that I need to merge the child elements.

How do I join these files together without putting them manually inside 1 JSON file using Terraform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably several ways of doing this. One would be as follows:

```
locals {

    rule_files = ["${path.module}/test1.json", "${path.module}/test2.json"]

    rules_joined = {
                    rules = flatten([for fname in local.rule_files: jsondecode(file(fname))["rules"]])
                   }
}
```

which gives `local.rules_joined` as:

```
{
  "rules" = [
    {
      "object-locator" = {
        "schema-name" = "SCHEMA_1"
        "table-name" = "TABLE_1"
      }
      "rule-action" = "rename"
      "rule-id" = "1"
      "rule-name" = "Rule name 1"
      "rule-target" = "schema"
      "rule-type" = "transformation"
      "value" = "main"
    },
    {
      "object-locator" = {
        "schema-name" = "SCHEMA_2"
        "table-name" = "TABLE_2"
      }
      "rule-action" = "rename"
      "rule-id" = "2"
      "rule-name" = "Rule name 2"
      "rule-target" = "schema"
      "rule-type" = "transformation"
      "value" = "main"
    },
  ]
}
```

To make it into a string, use `jsonencode(local.rules_joined)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks pretty good. But is it possible to set the folder name only? Like `db1`, then automatic include all the json files inside it.

Comment: Is it good to use [merge](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/merge.html) function?

Comment: @Miantian Using merge directly will not work, as you have same keys in your map. you would have to modify how you use the merge.

Comment: I created a new plan. For some reason we have to create multiple tasks. So about the file looping, and the resource reusable, I confirmed `for_each` but have no idea to do for files. Do you know? Sorry for asking you again. New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69537846/how-to-create-multiple-resources-with-different-names-and-target-files-with-terr